# Was there anything similar to the World War 1 Christmas truce in World War 2?

Tags: world-war-two, world-war-one, christmas

I know that there was an unofficial [Christmas truce](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Christmas_truce) during World War I, so now my question is this: was there anything similar during World War 2? It is close to the holidays as I am writing this question, so it makes sense to ask now.

I am mostly asking out of curiosity. I have checked Google and it did not give any answers on the subject, and likewise, Wikipedia does not really provide a good answer either.

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786)

Comment: The target markers set by Mosquito recon planes before bomb raids were colloquially known as Christmas trees (Weihnachtsbäume) but I guess that does not count.

Comment: Does [Phoney War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoney_War) qualify as an eight-month truce? ;-)

Comment: Not on such a large scale, but see https://www.taraross.com/post/tdih-christmas-eve-truce and https://europe.stripes.com/education/small-christmas-truce-wwii

Comment: The ["*Phoney War*"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phoney_War). Just as the Christmas Truce in WW1 was possible only because of the shortage of ammunition on both sides in Winter 1914, the *Phoney War* arose because of complete unreadiness of both the British and French in Fall and Winter 1940. The French not only lacked ammunition stocks, but realized only upon mobilization that they had made no provision either to exempt key strategic workers, or even to identify them. Identifying and extracting them from mobilized units took until March or April of 1940.